# Azure build pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

when I run the build pipeline I am getting ##[error]File not found: 'git'. I have an agent running on a server. I installed Git on the server. The pipeline is using this agent and is tied to an Azure repo. I am using simple script as below. Please advice.

trigger:
- master

pool: 'build agent'

## vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
- script: echo Hello, world!
  displayName: 'Run a one-line script'

- script: |
  echo Add other tasks to build, test, and deploy your project.
  echo See https://aka.ms/yaml
  displayName: 'Run a multi-line script'

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Here is all that you have to do if you want to create your Azure Pipeline:

1. Browse to Azure Pipelines and click on **New Pipeline**
   [image: Azure Pipelines Page]
2. Select **Azure Repo** when asked about the source of your codebase
   [image: Select Azure Repo]
3. Select your repository
   [image: Select your repository]
4. Review your Pipeline YAML and click on **Run**
   [image: Review your Pipeline YAML]

And voila, you have your first build running!

For customizing your build pipeline further, please check the various built-in [build and release tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/?view=azure-devops).

Here is the [YAML schema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema) for your reference.